# Firebase Analytics to BigQuery export not working

Tags: google-bigquery

[image]

Hi, I want to access Firebase analytics data through BigQuery, but I get the error in the images Google Analytics I have all the permissions.

[image]

Comment: Double check the permissions with some other admin. Your user might have limited access, and you don't see details. Also make sure you are indeed using the same email, as often we use multiple addresses.

Comment: I checked the permissions.
Firebase user > owner
Google Analytics > all permissions.
but it doesn't work.